# Matlab: creating a matrix whose rows consist of a linspace or similar pattern

Tags: matlab, matrix

Anybody know a fast way to produce a matrix consisting of a linspace for each row? For example, the sort of pattern I'm looking for in this matrix is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
...
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Anyone know any fast tricks to produce this WITHOUT using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured this out, so just in case anyone else was troubled by this, we can achieve this exact pattern by:

```
a=linspace(1,10,10);
b=ones(3,1)*a;
```

This will give:

```
>> a = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

>> b = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert this command: `transpose(ndgrid(1:10,1:n));`, where `n` is the number of rows desired in the result.

Comment: well wheres n is number of rows

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

Example:

```
>> B = repmat(1:10,[3 1])

B =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

You can vary the value of 3 there. You can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider these solutions:

1. With basic matrix indexing (taken from [here](http://www.vincentcheung.ca/research/matlabindexrepmat.html))

   ```
   b=a([1:size(a,1)]' * ones(1,NumToReplicate), :)  %row-wise replication
   b=a(:, ones(NumToReplicate, 1))  %column-wise replication
   ```
2. With `bsxfun`:

   ```
    bsxfun(@times,a,(ones(1,NumToReplicate))')  %row-wise replication
    bsxfun(@times,a',(ones(1,NumToReplicate)))  %column-wise replication
   ```

You are welcome to benchmark above two solutions with `repmat`.

Comment: Although I'm very fond of `bsxfun`, this case it not a good usage example.

Answer (score 1):

Another shortcut I can recommend is similar to `repmat`, but you specify a base array first of `a = 1:10;`.  Once you do this, you specify a series of `1`s in the first dimension when indexing which should produce a matrix of the same vectors with many rows as you want, where each row consists of the base array `a`.  As such:

```
%// number of times to replicate
n = 4;
a = 1:10;
a = a(ones(1,n),:);
```

Result:

```
a =

 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```